# Display object with axios in my react native project gives undefined

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, react-native, axios

I was trying to get request data from PHPMyAdmin and then output it on my react native project, and I use response.data.username, and yet I get undefined.

```js
const getInfo = () => {
  axios.get("https://luxrealest.com/includes/user_registration.php").then(
    (response) => {
      console.log(response.username);
      setDataInfo(response.data.username + " " + response.data.email);
    })
}
getInfo()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.24.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-u9akINsQsAkG9xjc1cnGF4zw5TFDwkxuc9vUp5dltDWYCSmyd0meygbvgXrlc/z7/o4a19Fb5V0OUE58J7dcyw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Expected

```
Object {
  "": Object {
    "email": "myke@myke.com",
    "id": "11",
    "username": "myke",
  },
  "1": Object {
    "email": "aisosa.erharuyi11@gmail.com",
    "id": "12",
    "username": "General.Bigman",
  },
  "2": Object {
    "email": "amiatorjay@gmail.com",
    "id": "13",
    "username": "Jaycee",
  },
}
```

Comment: I tried to make you a [mcve] - I get CORS errors when I lowercase Axios

Comment: @mplungjan, using Postman I was able to get the response from that URL. In the browser I also get CORS error.

Comment: Postman does not give CORS errors. The endpoint you are trying to reach needs to implement [Access control allow origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)

Answer (score 0):

Given the shape of your data you need to iterate over this object like this:

```
 for (let key in response.data) {
     setDataInfo(response.data[key].username + " " + response.data[key].email);
 }
```

This of course will call `setDataInfo` 3 times for your data. If you want only a specific user you will need to add additional logic.

Comment: Please what kind of logic, can you show me an example because it is not printing out

Comment: You can try a few things: 1. check the browser console if you get any errors such as CORS that has been mentioned in comments. 2. if you get the response add for example `console.log(response.data[key].username)` in that loop and see if you get the expected value. 3. also add `.catch` after `.then` in the axios call and log/display the errors so the users will be aware if there any problems fetching the data.

Comment: okay... Thanks, I will see to it.